Systemd: do not suspend if operation is performed
How to configure systemd so if an operation is being performed, do nothing on systemctl suspend and optionally suspend after the operation is completed?
Operations example: archive extraction, rsync, timeshift, package manager updates, computational fluid dynamics code doing calculations, etc...

You are looking for systemd-inhibit.

@larsks, but it is to be used to execute program, meanwhile when I use GUI apps, e.g. file-roller started from nemo, I cannot launch it via systemd-inhibit. Can it be attached to a process? I cannot find this possibility
